# Preprocessing before camel file poller starts reading file

Tags: apache-camel

We have implemented a file poller in our current implementation to read a file of thousands of records and split them using streaming. Now we got a new user requirement to save details or meta data of the file like file name, file size, directory, file creation date etc to DB as an xml before file processing starts every day.

I have created an endpoint to create the XML using xslt, to validate the generated XML and to save it to the DB. But all the file records will be sent to this endpoint after file poller starts reading XML.

Can i solve this using filters? If i use filters i wont be able to call my xslt route and  won't be able to access file properties like `${file:name}` or `${file:size}` or camel headers to get meta data of the file. How can i solve this?

Here is the route sample:

```
<route id="RouteA"> 
    <from uri="file://directoryA/?autoCreate=true&amp;delete=true&amp;readLock=changed&amp;moveFailed=archive&amp/>

    <!-- this route takes care of creating XML, validation and saving xml to DB etc -->
    <to uri="mock:fileCreationEndPoint" />

    <split streaming="true">
        <tokenize token="\n"/>
        <to uri="flatpack:delim:flatpackConfig/config.pzmap.xmldelimiter=|&amp;ignoreFirstRecord=false"/>
    </split>
</route>
```

Comment: why do you need this *before* ? the from file will not read the file it detects the file, and places a java.io.File as the body. Its only when you access the file in the Camel route its read. So your route looks good to me. You can save the meta-data before splitting.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. If i use above route then all the content of file will be sent to mock:fileCreationEndPoint before splitting which i don't want as this mock end point  will just create file meta data to store to DB. Is there a way to avoid sending file content to this mock endpoint.

Comment: As long as you dont touch the body of the file in the Metadata generator the file is not loaded. Claus is correct in what he is saying.

Comment: I tried to debug using a bean, checked the body of the exchange and i could see body type as file based but when i added log statements in blueprint file like <log  loggingLevel="INFO" message="Body info : ${body} "/> its logging whole content of the file and even my xslt transformation is failing as whole file content is passed to XSLT file. What difference does it make to access body in log statements using ${body} in blue print file and accessing in a bean using exchange.getIn().getBody()?

Comment: If you log `${body}` then of course Camel has to read the file. As long as you don't log the body and only access the file meta data, the file content is not read.

Comment: Thanks peter, I included logs only for debugging purposes and I  tried to create file meta data xml using xslt. For that i am passing all file meta data header elements as params to xslt and constructing xml but when i included <xsl:template match="/"> in xsl seems like whole file is loaded over there. May be other option is using jaxb to generate xml. If xsldid not work i will try jaxb way. Thanks for help.